# what is the daemon thread for Hashed wheel timer #1?

Tags: java, eclipse

When debugging, I noticed there is a thread named Hashed wheel timer #1, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently [HashedWheelTimer](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/util/HashedWheelTimer.html) is a Netty class that implements a kind of timer.  The thread is created by that class.